# Looping PHP array through PHP table

Tags: php, wordpress

Without using echo, how do I get the `$report` array of records to populate this html table?

The first row `$report[0]` shows up fine but I'm not sure how to get it loop through the table and automatically display the other rows.

```
$report = get_field('maths_month_report');
$report1 = $report[0];
$report2 = implode('</td><td>', $report1);

if (in_array('Maths', $subjecttitle)) {
return '

<table width="100%" id="report">
<tr>

<th width="10%">Month</th>
<th width="10%">Progress</th>
<th width="10%">Well-being</th>
<th width="35%">Remarks</th>
<th width="35%">Target</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>'. $report2 .'</td>
</tr>
</table>

';
}
```

Comment: you need to use PHP loop algorithm. You can use foreach. Ex: `foreach( $report as $re ){
    // $report1, $report2, in_array etc codes
    // $html .= 'Your table code';
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<table width="100%" id="report">';
$str .= '<tr>
    <th width="10%">Month</th>
    <th width="10%">Progress</th>
    <th width="10%">Well-being</th>
    <th width="35%">Remarks</th>
    <th width="35%">Target</th>
    </tr>';
foreach($report as $v){
    $str .= '<tr>
    <td>'. $v['val1'] .'</td>
    <td>'. $v['val2'] .'</td>
    <td>'. $v['val3'] .'</td>
    <td>'. $v['val4'] .'</td>
    <td>'. $v['val5'] .'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$str .= '</table>';

return $str;
```

i hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'm still a bit newb so it took me a while to figure out val1, val2, etc should be the field names for the records. Absolutely fantastic!!!

Comment: val1, val2 are field names in associated array.